# Windows Azure storage emulator Failed to covert date time string to valid time stamp

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-storage

I'm a newbi of Windows Azure. I'm developing a simple asp.net FileManager Portal wich use Windows Azure storage. I haven't an account on windows azure portal, so I tried to use storage emulator. Everytime I try to run the storage using Visual Studio i have the following behaviour:

1. start compute emulator
2. start storage emulator
3. start web role, but its shell shows me this messages:

   [MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2013-04-24T23:58:59.234Z
   [MonAgentHost] Error:     2
   [MonAgentHost] Error:     3108
   [MonAgentHost] Error:     14084
   [MonAgentHost] Error:     SelfMonitoring
   [MonAgentHost] Error:     0
   [MonAgentHost] Error:     824f03af-5b9b-4ea5-84fa-6bd04de
   [MonAgentHost] Error:     selfmon.cpp
   [MonAgentHost] Error:     MASelfMon::GetProcCntrs
   [MonAgentHost] Error:     1421
   [MonAgentHost] Error:     ffffffffc0000bb8
   [MonAgentHost] Error:     0
   [MonAgentHost] Error:
   [MonAgentHost] Error:     PdhAddCounter(\Process(MonAgentHost#0)\ID Process) failed
   [MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2013-04-24T23:58:59.277Z
   [MonAgentHost] Error:     2
   [MonAgentHost] Error:     3108
   [MonAgentHost] Error:     4508
   [MonAgentHost] Error:     FileListener.dll
   [MonAgentHost] Error:     0
   [MonAgentHost] Error:     a4827672-7864-4b12-9994-848f8d0
   [MonAgentHost] Error:     filelistener.cpp
   [MonAgentHost] Error:     FileListener::StringToTimeStamp
   [MonAgentHost] Error:     281
   [MonAgentHost] Error:     ffffffff80010003
   [MonAgentHost] Error:     0
   [MonAgentHost] Error:
   [MonAgentHost] Error:     ERROR: Failed to covert date time string 2013-04-24T23.58.56.001Z to valid time stamp 
   [Diagnostics]: Checking for configuration updates 24/04/2013 23.59.08.

and it loops on this errors.
any suggestions? maybe it's a datetime format problem... but how can i solve it?

EDIT:
this is the output of my shell

```
[fabric] Role Instance: deployment18(55).SafetyPlatform.SafetyPlatform.Web.0
[fabric] Role state Started
[Diagnostics]: UpdateState(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorStartupInfo, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration, )
[Diagnostics]: Acquired mutex
[Diagnostics] Information: C:\Users\Antonio\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\e2f7627c-4994-45f8-9faf-e6b79b9014d6\directory\DiagnosticStore\Monitor
[Diagnostics] Information: C:\Users\Antonio\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\SafetyPlatform\SafetyPlatform.Azure\csx\Debug\roles\SafetyPlatform.Web\diagnostics\x64\monitor\MonAgentHost.exe -LocalPath "C:\Users\Antonio\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\e2f7627c-4994-45f8-9faf-e6b79b9014d6\directory\DiagnosticStore\Monitor" -StaticConfigFile "C:\Users\Antonio\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\e2f7627c-4994-45f8-9faf-e6b79b9014d6\directory\DiagnosticStore\Monitor\Configuration\mastaticconfig.xml" -ConfigFile "C:\Users\Antonio\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\e2f7627c-4994-45f8-9faf-e6b79b9014d6\directory\DiagnosticStore\Monitor\Configuration\maconfig.xml" -ShutDownEvent WADDM-ShutDown-3db0f5b65bf94bb793a6f8cebd833fe7 -InitializedEvent WADM-StartUp-3db0f5b65bf94bb793a6f8cebd833fe7 -parent 10416 -events
[MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2013-04-25T16:47:04.167Z
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     4752
[MonAgentHost] Error:     11536
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SelfMonitoring
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     dcc23483-2ce0-4897-8675-0cb23d5
[MonAgentHost] Error:     selfmon.cpp
[MonAgentHost] Error:     MASelfMon::GetProcCntrs
[MonAgentHost] Error:     1421
[MonAgentHost] Error:     ffffffffc0000bb8
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     
[MonAgentHost] Error:     PdhAddCounter(\Process(MonAgentHost#0)\ID Process) failed
[Diagnostics]: Creating config channel server
[MonAgentHost] Output: Agent will exit when WADDM-ShutDown-3db0f5b65bf94bb793a6f8cebd833fe7 is signaled.
[MonAgentHost] Output: Will signal WADM-StartUp-3db0f5b65bf94bb793a6f8cebd833fe7 after the agent is initialized.
[MonAgentHost] Output: Registered as an event consumer.
[MonAgentHost] Output: Agent will exit when parent process 10416 exits.
[MonAgentHost] Output: Monitoring Agent Started
[Diagnostics]: Starting configuration channel polling
[runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   OnStart()
[runtime] Role entrypoint . COMPLETED OnStart()
[runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   Run()
[Diagnostics]: Checking for configuration updates 25/04/2013 18:48:04.
[Diagnostics]: Signalling process restart on event = WADDM-ShutDown-3db0f5b65bf94bb793a6f8cebd833fe7
[MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2013-04-25T16:48:05.441Z
[MonAgentHost] Error:     3
[MonAgentHost] Error:     4752
[MonAgentHost] Error:     11536
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SelfMonitoring
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     dcc23483-2ce0-4897-8675-0cb23d5
[MonAgentHost] Error:     selfmon.cpp
[MonAgentHost] Error:     MASelfMon::StartTerminationCountdown
[MonAgentHost] Error:     1088
[MonAgentHost] Error:     10011
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     
[MonAgentHost] Error:     Not starting termination thread inside a client hosted monitoring agent
[MonAgentHost] Output: Exiting the monitoring agent 4752 after the shutdown event was signaled.
[MonAgentHost] Output: Monitoring Agent Stopped
[Diagnostics] Information: Diagnostic process exited with code: 0
[Diagnostics] Information: C:\Users\Antonio\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\e2f7627c-4994-45f8-9faf-e6b79b9014d6\directory\DiagnosticStore\Monitor
[Diagnostics] Information: C:\Users\Antonio\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\SafetyPlatform\SafetyPlatform.Azure\csx\Debug\roles\SafetyPlatform.Web\diagnostics\x64\monitor\MonAgentHost.exe -LocalPath "C:\Users\Antonio\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\e2f7627c-4994-45f8-9faf-e6b79b9014d6\directory\DiagnosticStore\Monitor" -StaticConfigFile "C:\Users\Antonio\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\e2f7627c-4994-45f8-9faf-e6b79b9014d6\directory\DiagnosticStore\Monitor\Configuration\mastaticconfig.xml" -ConfigFile "C:\Users\Antonio\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\e2f7627c-4994-45f8-9faf-e6b79b9014d6\directory\DiagnosticStore\Monitor\Configuration\maconfig.xml" -ShutDownEvent WADDM-ShutDown-c5e4e166e3ca45a69d0f30d7785f20f9 -InitializedEvent WADM-StartUp-c5e4e166e3ca45a69d0f30d7785f20f9 -parent 10416 -events
[MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2013-04-25T16:48:08.041Z
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     9400
[MonAgentHost] Error:     11948
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SelfMonitoring
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     8bc9ab18-a05b-4a5c-b054-963f010
[MonAgentHost] Error:     selfmon.cpp
[MonAgentHost] Error:     MASelfMon::GetProcCntrs
[MonAgentHost] Error:     1421
[MonAgentHost] Error:     ffffffffc0000bb8
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     
[MonAgentHost] Error:     PdhAddCounter(\Process(MonAgentHost#0)\ID Process) failed
[MonAgentHost] Output: Agent will exit when WADDM-ShutDown-c5e4e166e3ca45a69d0f30d7785f20f9 is signaled.
[MonAgentHost] Output: Will signal WADM-StartUp-c5e4e166e3ca45a69d0f30d7785f20f9 after the agent is initialized.
[MonAgentHost] Output: Registered as an event consumer.
[MonAgentHost] Output: Agent will exit when parent process 10416 exits.
[MonAgentHost] Output: Monitoring Agent Started
[Diagnostics]: Starting configuration channel polling
```

After that, it continues with diagnostics (i think this is normal)

Comment: What time zone are you in and how are your date/time settings (Control Panel --> Region) set on your computer?

Comment: I'm from Italy and my date/time is dd/MM/yyyy HH.mm.ss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able to reproduce this error on my machine by changing my computer's locale to Italy. I believe you have stumbled upon a bug with compute emulator. What's happening is that compute emulator (rather diagnostics monitor agent) is not liking the default time separator (`.`) based on your locale (which is Italy).

I did find a workaround if it's acceptable to you. The workaround is to change the default time separator from `.` to `:`. I tried the same and it didn't give me the error after changing it. See the screenshot below for more details.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @Gaurav Mantri. this solve the problem about time. but i continue to read the erro about MA EVENT. If you want to help me, i can edit my question with the output of azure's shell

Comment: I can certainly try to help you out. Please edit your question.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I edit the question pasting all output from starting my asp.net example.

Comment: For your 2nd error, can you check out the resolution posted in this blog post: http://www.infosysblogs.com/microsoft/2011/06/mystery_of_the_windows_azure_d.html. HTH.

Comment: thank you! i tried it, but it doesn't solve the problem i looked aroud and i found this  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuretroubleshooting/thread/57c24738-53bd-40da-9819-bb217d0baa72/ and i have the same situation. pff thank you for your time and don't warry, it's a my problem now :)